# Not getting Ios application tab in properties of IOS project, How to set Splash Screen in IOS without this using storyboard - Xamarin

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, splash-screen

I am using `Xamarin Forms` and want to set splash screen for `ios project` and followed these steps provided in this link.

[creating-splash-screen-xamarin-forms](https://xamarinhelp.com/creating-splash-screen-xamarin-forms/)

but i'm not getting the `Ios Application` tab in properties of ios project. i am getting options as in below image as in recent release they have removed the option.

[image]

can anyone explain me step by step process for setting the splash screen in ios with some other way?

i am new to xamarin, any help is appreciated, thank you so much.

Comment: Open the `Info.plist` in your project and go to the `Visual Asset` page

Comment: @SushiHangover yes i did that but how to import images after that, can you please explain in detail?

Comment: Make sure you use a storyboard, not an image or it will not work on later iPhones like iPhone X. Instructions here https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/launch-screens/

Comment: thank you so much @SteveChadbourne and this link is really helpful.

Comment: @SteveChadbourne That was an Xcode bug that was fixed in 9.1, using an asset catalog works fine.

Comment: @SushiHangover you learn something new every day!